# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'csv'

Tags: python

I am trying to write a CSV file and I have code to create a document with a header file this code will take inputs to write to that same file.

```
class CSVFile:

    def __init__(self, doctitle):
        #creates the physical doc on the disk
        #creates the header row in the .csv file
        self.doctitle = doctitle
        self.f = open(doctitle + ".csv", 'w+')
        self.f.write("vianumber, innerdiameter, outerdiamter, ratio \n")
        self.closedoc()
        return


    def appendrow(self, doctitle, vianumber, innerdiameter, outerdiamter, ratio):
        #called for each measured via
        self.f = open(doctitle + ".csv", 'a+')
        self.f.write(vianumber, innerdiameter, outerdiamter, ratio)
        self.closedoc()
        return

    def closedoc(self):
        #filize the document
        self.f.close()
        return
```

The error message I get is the following:

```
 CSVFile.appendrow("", "test", 2, 3, 4, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-07d259b7d2fa>", line 1, in <module>
    CSVFile.appendrow("", "test", 2, 3, 4, 5)

  File "C:/Users/Brook/Desktop/Senior Design/CSV file script.py", line 23, in appendrow
    self.f = open(doctitle + ".csv", 'a+')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'f'
```

Comment: shouldnt this `self.doctitle` be just `doctitle`?

Comment: Changing from self.doctitle to doctitle doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please include the full error message and the relevant code. The error was not likely produced in the code that you posted.

Comment: Aside from that, you're not writing any separators to your file. Why aren't you using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)?

Comment: I thought that using the + "csv" would make it into a csv file

Comment: Please add _all_ relevant code - namely, how you initialize the `CSVFile` and call its methods.

Comment: Apparently, you have not created a `CSVFile` object. That's why `.f` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not instantiating an object. Your call is `CSVFile.appendrow("", "test", 2, 3, 4, 5)`.
Essentially, it means that for the self parameter of `appendrow` you are passing an empty string argument `""`.

Try something along lines of `CSVFile("test").appendrow("test", 2, 3, 4, 5)`

You have an error in the `self.f.write` call in your code as well, but I will let you fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Your class and the way you use it have a lot of issues, such as:

- You do not use the stored file name.
- You do not use the standard CSV writer.
- You do not use `with` blocks.
- You do not create a class object.
- You create unnecessary object attributes.
- You pass the `self` parameter to an object method.

Here is an improved version of your code.

```
import csv

class CSVFile:

    def __init__(self, doctitle):
        self.doctitle = doctitle + ".csv"
        with open(doctitle, 'w+') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(["vianumber", "innerdiameter",
                             "outerdiamter", "ratio"])

    def appendrow(self, vianumber, innerdiameter, outerdiamter, ratio):
        #called for each measured via
        with open(self.doctitle, 'a+') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow([vianumber, innerdiameter, outerdiamter, ratio])

    #def closedoc(self): -- Not needed!
        #filize the document

mycsv = CSVFile("foo")
mycsv.appendrow(2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: Because `CSVFile.appendrow(2,3,4,5)` is incorrect. Please read my example carefully.

Comment: using csv.appendrow(2,3,4,5) gives an error as well

Comment: csv.appendrow(2,3,4,5)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-79-49b8159c3024>", line 1, in <module>
    csv.appendrow(2,3,4,5)

AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'appendrow'

Comment: Right, calling the variable `csv` was a bad idea, updated. But the fact that you saw that message means that you did not execute the second line from the bottom.